# Why does my for loop in C++ not iterate as many times as its supposed to?

Tags: c++

I am relatively new to C++. I made this for loop so that the user can input data, which will then be added into an array. It seems to work, except that it only iterates 7 times when i run it. I would like it to run more than that, but it does not seem to work. Thank you for the help.

```
int numberCourses = 0;
string allCourses[] = {};
for (int i = 0; i <= 50; i++)
{ 
    cout << "Course #" << i << ": " << flush;
    string courseCode;
    cin >> courseCode;

    if (courseCode == "EXIT" || courseCode == "Exit" || courseCode == "exit"){
        break;
    }
    else{
        allCourses[i] = courseCode;
        numberCourses++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the loop adding strings to an array that contains only one element (or completely empty, too lazy to verify). As such, the program crashes miserably. It's a miracle that it lasted even seven iterations. I expect it to crash on the 2nd one.

Comment: You have undefined behavior

Comment: Declare the array to be `string allCourses[51];` in order to avoid your problem (because the for-loop can run from 0 to 50 inclusive).

Comment: Use std::vector with push_back, not an array.

Comment: You should *transform* strings to all lowercase or all uppercase before comparing, so you don't miss out on cases like "eXit" or "ExIt".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> string allCourses[] = {};
> ```

Automatic arrays of 0 elements are not allowed. This is an ill-formed program, and a compiler should tell you so.

> ```
> allCourses[i] = courseCode;
> ```

You access elements that don't exist in the array. The behaviour is undefined.

---

Simple solution: Create an array with enough elements:

```
 string allCourses[51];
```

Comment: You don't even need the explicit initialization, default-initialization does the right thing.

Comment: @Quentin good point.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in:

```
string allCourses[] = {};
```

use

```
vector<string> allCourses(51);
```

instead. Potentially you can also do:

```
string allCourses[51];
```

but `vector` is better. The initialisation you have for `allCourses` creates an empty array of strings so doing `allCourses[i]` for any `i` is undefined behavior.

Alternative solution with `vector` would be:

```
vector<string> allCourses;
```

and inside the loop use [`vector::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) to insert element at the end of the `vector`:

```
allCourses.push_back(courseCode);
```

This way you also don't need to keep track of `numberCourses` as it will be equal to [`allCourses.size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size).

Full code would look like this:

```
vector<string> allCourses;
for (int i = 0; i <= 50; i++)
{ 
    cout << "Course #" << i << ": " << flush;
    string courseCode;
    cin >> courseCode;

    if (courseCode == "EXIT" || courseCode == "Exit" || courseCode == "exit"){
        break;
    }
    else{
        allCourses.push_back(courseCode);
    }
}
int numberCourses = allCourses.size();
```

Comment: I think that you should add the 2 correct snippet. Austin is clearly a beginner   and many has fall in the same pitfall. an exemple with vector push_back is may be a good idea.

Comment: @VGE how about now?

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work as intended because you are trying to "push" data into your array.  Arrays in c++ are not dynamically allocated.  You might want to try using some other container in the std library rather than an array.

Specifically, you have declared `allCourses` as an empty array.  It's done.  You can't add elements to this empty array.  If, however, you declared `allCourses` as a static array of `N` elements, like so:

```
#define N 51
string allCourses[N];
```

This would allow 51 elements.

Another option would be to use a `std::vector<std::string>`, which abstracts an underlying array, but allows the addition of elements dynamically.

If you use a vector, you'll have to use `.push_back(X)` to add elements to the vector.

Or, as a quick hack to just change the type to allow the rest of your code to run as-is, use a `std::map<int, std::string>`

Using a `std::map<int, std::string>` allows you to dynamically access the container elements just as you already have by an `int` index, even though that's not the intended purpose of `std::map`, it can be used this way.

Comment: `string allCourses[N] = { 0 };` would initialize the first array element with `0`, which would be interpreted as a null pointer constant in this context. Null pointer is an invalid initializer for `std::string` object. Why did you put that `0` between the `{}`?

Comment: ^^  You're right.  Edited.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to gradually add stuff to an array, use a `vector`. (Actually, use `vector` whenever you need an array until you get a lot more experienced.)

```
std::vector<std::string> allCourses;

// inside the if:
  allCourses.push_back(courseCode);
```

Now you can also get rid of `numberCourses`, since you can just use `allCourses.size()` to get the number of created courses.

Answer (score 0):

Before you do anything else I suggest you cease using the `<=` operator in your for-loop conditional expression; change it to `<` (and rewrite/retest accordingly) – you will not be sorry. Using `<=` and `>=` operators in for-loop conditionals always introduces ambiguity and will open the door for wonky (and possibly even undefined) behavior!